# How to create a PHP counter that assigns a unique id to each repeater row?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

So I have some code that is spitting out the Repeater field type as long as there are instances of this field in my WP backend. It looks like this

```
<div class="custom-product-list">

  <div class="cpl-center">

  <?php

  // check if the repeater field has rows of data
  if( have_rows('custom_products') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('custom_products') ) : the_row();

  ?>
     <div class="custom-product">

      <div class="col col_1">
        <div class="custom-mobile-image">
          <img src="<?php the_sub_field('product_image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('product_name'); ?>" />
        </div><!-- .custom-mobile-image -->
        <h2><?php the_sub_field('product_name'); ?></h2>
        <p><?php the_sub_field('product_description'); ?></p>
        <h3>Benefits</h3>
        <?php

        // check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('benefits') ):

        ?>

          <ul>

        <?php

          // loop through the rows of data
          while ( have_rows('benefits') ) : the_row();

        ?>

          <li><?php the_sub_field('benefit'); ?></li>

        <?php

          endwhile;

        ?>

          </ul>

        <?php

        endif;

        ?>
      </div><!-- .col -->

      <div class="col col_2 last">

        <div class="custom-product-image">
          <img src="<?php the_sub_field('product_image'); ?>"alt="<?php the_sub_field('product_name'); ?>" />
        </div><!-- .custom-product-image -->

        <div class="col col_3">
          <h3>For Best Results</h3>
          <?php

          // check if the repeater field has rows of data
          if( have_rows('for_best_results') ):

          ?>

            <ul>

          <?php

            // loop through the rows of data
            while ( have_rows('for_best_results') ) : the_row();

          ?>

            <li><?php the_sub_field('result'); ?></li>

          <?php

            endwhile;

          ?>

            </ul>

          <?php

          endif;

          ?>
        </div><!-- .col -->
        <div class="col col_4 last">
          <h3>Type</h3>
          <?php

          // check if the repeater field has rows of data
          if( have_rows('type') ):

          ?>

            <ul>

          <?php

            // loop through the rows of data
            while ( have_rows('type') ) : the_row();

          ?>

            <li><?php the_sub_field('entry'); ?></li>

          <?php

            endwhile;

          ?>

            </ul>

          <?php

          endif;

          ?>
        </div><!-- .col -->

        <div class="clear"></div><!-- .clear -->

      </div><!-- .col -->

      <div class="clear"></div><!-- .clear -->

    </div><!-- .custom-product -->

  <?php

    endwhile;

  endif;

  ?>
```

I want to add a counter that will give a unique id to each new row or instance of the repeater field so I can link to it as a section of the page.

I tried to do it myself but I created a loop that went on forever... can someone advise on a path forward?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a unique id to each repeater row in each section, something like this may work for you. You'd obviously have to do this for each particular section

```
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
<?php if( have_rows('benefits') ): 
    //Introduce a counter for each section
    $benefits_sub_item=1;
?>
    <ul>
        <?php // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('benefits') ) : the_row();
        ?>
            <li id="benefit-item-<?php echo $benefits_sub_item;"><?php the_sub_field('benefit'); ?></li>
        <?php
            $benefits_sub_item++;
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```